# Cannot add constraint between UIButton and UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, constraints

I have an UIViewController with design shown on storyboard as below

[image: View hierarchy]

I was unable to figure out why I cannot add constraint between the "Watson" button and the UICollectionView by using drag drop method (the image lies under Watson button is a cell that belongs to an UICollectionView). I tried many times dragging from Watson button to the under Thumbnail Collection view but seems like no constraint between them was made.

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add constraint between the "Watson" button and the UICollectionView.

You can only add constraints between view and its superview or subviews or between view and its siblings (views that have common superview).

For example, you can add constraint between "Watson" and MainCell, or between "Watson" and "Album".

Comment: oh I see, thanks a lot :D I want the space between the bottom collection view and the Watson button to be 20pt regardless of screen size, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: If you want that behaviour, maybe you should reorder views and subviews. For example, maybe you don't need Watson button to be placed in MainCell of MainCollectionView. I don't know the details and what are requirements to be more helpful.